# What is the -D compiler flag C++ (clang, GNU, MSVC)

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, gnu

Okay I am assuming that the `-D` prefix means `#define` whatever variable name is followed by it, however I cannot find any documentation on this makefile feature for compiler flags.

`CXX=clang -DTHISISPREPROCESSORVARIABLE`

So `-DTHISISPREPROCESSORVARIABLE` in the make process would define the preprocessor variable `THISISPREPROCESSORVARIABLE` and would make the follow `cout` compiled.

```
#ifdef THISISPREPROCESSORVARIABLE
     std::cout << "this should exist with the -D" << endl;
#endif
```

Is this the right assumption? It seems to work, just can anyone confirm this `-D` is referring to `#define` (anyone have any links to some makefile docs that can fill in all these commands definitions?)

Comment: _"Is this the right assumption?"_ Yes, it is. Did you experiment with it? Did you get any results disproving your assumption?

Comment: It's a compiler option, not a make option. So you should look in the compiler documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html),
[MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx), and 
[Intel](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruoptdu.htm), all have this flag documented, and Clang just uses GCC flags by default.  I just found it on [Clang's help page waaaay at the bottom](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) (for clang-cl for windows), and [harmic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411457/harmic)  found it more clearly [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clang) for linux.

> Execute `clang-cl /?` to see a list of supported options:
>     `/D <macro[=value]>`     Define macro

[harmic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411457/harmic) observes that these are *compiler* flags, and have nothing at all to do with makefiles, which is why you can't find it in the makefile docs.  These flags can be put inside a makefile which will pass them to the compiler, but are not part of makefiles.

Comment: Thanks the GCC link is exactly what I was looking for! Yeah it looks like clang follows all the same standards.

Comment: @Danoli3: clang accepts all GCC flags I've ever tried, though it definitely ignores several of them.

Comment: Also `clang-cl` is a windows command line, just `clang --help` for unix based systems.

Comment: @Danoli3: I haven't yet found clang documentation on `/D` that wasn't about `clang-cl`.