# what do these gcc options do?

Tags: c, gcc

Our professor in a lecture example compiled his code with a kind of options/args like this: `gcc -O3 -DDOUBLE -lm -o outputfil inputfile.c`. I researched and I found out that -O3 is a kind of level 3 optimization the compiler does to the code, but I couldn't find any info about the left options (-lm & -DDOUBLE).

Comment: See the manual: [gcc preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) and [gcc link options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options).

Comment: This question can be closed as a combination duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226874